1 watt of power defines as?
Imagine you have a light bulb of 1 watt power. Then, is 1 watt defined as
•1 joule of electric energy transformed to 1 joule of light energy in 1 sec?
•what exactly is meant by 'consumption' of energy in a light bulb? What has it to do with watts?

An incandescent light bulb is a resistor that gets hot enough that the black body emission has lots of visible light. Most is not in the visible.

1 Joule/sec of energy is emitted by the 1 W bulb, but much of that energy will be in the form of heat.

How much energy in photons is getting emitted.

@DavidWhite, A "1W" laser emits 1W of optical energy, but a "1W" light bulb consumes 1W of electrical energy and emits significantly less optical energy. To make matters even worse, they're still marketing "60W equivalent" light bulbs (and other sizes too) that emit as much light as a 60W incandescent bulb used to do, but which only consume maybe 8 or 10W of electrical energy.

@SolomonSlow this isn't meant to be criticism.  However, using wording implying that energy is "consumed" may confuse physics novices regarding conservation of energy arguments.

@DavidWhite, Aaagh! Payback! Usually it's me who's telling others how their words could be misinterpreted by newbies. You are right. I should have said that both lasers and lightbulbs convert electrical energy to light and heat. None of that energy disappears. But when comparing whose is bigger, with lasers the convention is to say how many milliwatts or watts of light comes out, while with light bulbs, the convention is to say how many watts of electric power go in.
